# I updated my IPython from 3.x to 4.1.2 and after that Spyder can't load the IPython console anymore

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, spyder

I tried uninstalling and again insatlling spyder. I deleted all ~/.spyder2 settings.. but no luck.. 
Following errors are displayed in the Spyder's internal console:

```
    /home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/log.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.log has moved to traitlets.log
      warn("IPython.utils.log has moved to traitlets.log")
    /home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/nbformat/current.py:19: UserWarning: IPython.nbformat.current is deprecated.

    - use IPython.nbformat for read/write/validate public API
    - use IPython.nbformat.vX directly to composing notebooks of a particular version

      """)
    /home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
      warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 656, in toggle_view
        self.create_new_client(give_focus=False)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 830, in create_new_client
        menu_actions=self.menu_actions)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/ipython.py", line 407, in __init__
        local_kernel=False)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/ipython.py", line 175, in __init__
        super(IPythonShellWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/rich_jupyter_widget.py", line 53, in __init__
        super(RichJupyterWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/jupyter_widget.py", line 112, in __init__
        super(JupyterWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/frontend_widget.py", line 181, in __init__
        super(FrontendWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/history_console_widget.py", line 28, in __init__
        super(HistoryConsoleWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/console_widget.py", line 211, in __init__
        LoggingConfigurable.__init__(self, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 85, in __init__
        self.config = config
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 558, in __set__
        self.set(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 532, in set
        new_value = self._validate(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 564, in _validate
        value = self.validate(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1589, in validate
        self.error(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1436, in error
        raise TraitError(e)
    traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'config' trait of an IPythonShellWidget instance must be a Config, but a value of class 'IPython.config.loader.Config' (i.e. {'IPythonWidget': {'gui_completion': 'droplist', 'enable_calltips': True, 'kind': 'rich', 'paging': 'none', 'buffer_size': 500}}) was specified.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 830, in create_new_client
        menu_actions=self.menu_actions)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/ipython.py", line 407, in __init__
        local_kernel=False)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/ipython.py", line 175, in __init__
        super(IPythonShellWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/rich_jupyter_widget.py", line 53, in __init__
        super(RichJupyterWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/jupyter_widget.py", line 112, in __init__
        super(JupyterWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/frontend_widget.py", line 181, in __init__
        super(FrontendWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/history_console_widget.py", line 28, in __init__
        super(HistoryConsoleWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtconsole/console_widget.py", line 211, in __init__
        LoggingConfigurable.__init__(self, **kw)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 85, in __init__
        self.config = config
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 558, in __set__
        self.set(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 532, in set
        new_value = self._validate(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 564, in _validate
        value = self.validate(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1589, in validate
        self.error(obj, value)
      File "/home/mm/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1436, in error
        raise TraitError(e)
    traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'config' trait of an IPythonShellWidget instance must be a Config, but a value of class 'IPython.config.loader.Config' (i.e. {'IPythonWidget': {'gui_completion': 'droplist', 'enable_calltips': True, 'kind': 'rich', 'paging': 'none', 'buffer_size': 500}}) was specified.
```

I am using python2.7, ipython 4.1.2, ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I have found so far is by running ipython inside the python console by entering this.

```
import IPython
Ipython.start_ipython()
```

However no solutions found yet for running a native ipython console inside spyder.